# Cassandra python driver - frozen with Object Mapper

Tags: python, cassandra, cassandra-driver, cassandra-python-driver

I'm trying to declare and create (using `sync_table`) Cassandra table using a Object Mapper from python Cassandra driver (`cassandra-driver` package version 3.14), but I can't find a way to define a frozen value in a collection.

Is there a way to define a frozen using Object Mapper or I have to manually write a `CREATE TABLE` statement to do that and then use Object Mapper only to make queries?

Answer (score 0):

are not [UDF](http://datastax.github.io/python-driver/cqlengine/models.html#user-defined-types) what you are searching for?